# spring-jms OutboundGateway does not pick up reply

Tags: spring-jms

Maybe it's a stupid question and I'm missing something very simple, but I'm really stuck.
I'm using ActiveMQ 5.5.1 and SI 2.1.4

My configs snippets:

---SERVER---

```
    <beans:bean id="connectionFactory"   class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <beans:property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</beans:bean>


   <beans:bean id="listQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="name" value="LIST_QUEUE"/>
    </beans:bean>   

   <beans:bean id="replyListQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="name" value="REPLY_LIST_QUEUE"/>
    </beans:bean>             

    <channel id="replyListChannel"/> 
    <channel id="listIn" />
    <channel id="listDriver"/>
    <channel id="listStock"/>    


    <jms:inbound-channel-adapter id="listInJms"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        destination="listQueue"
        channel="listIn"        
        auto-startup="true">
        <poller fixed-rate="3000"/>
    </jms:inbound-channel-adapter>  



    <header-value-router input-channel="listIn" header-name="List"
            default-output-channel="nullChannel">        
        <mapping value="Driver" channel="listDriver" />
        <mapping value="Stock" channel="listStock" />
    </header-value-router>

    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        channel="replyListChannel"
        destination="replyListQueue"
        auto-startup="true">                 
    </jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

---CLIENT---

```
<beans:bean id="connectionFactory"  class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <beans:property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</beans:bean>      

<beans:bean id="requestListQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="LIST_QUEUE"/>
</beans:bean>         

<beans:bean id="replyListQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="REPLY_LIST_QUEUE"/>
</beans:bean> 


<channel id="requestListChannel">
    <queue capacity="20"/>
</channel>   

<channel id="listStockChannel">
    <queue capacity="20"/>
</channel>   

<channel id="listDriverChannel">
    <queue capacity="20"/>
</channel>       

<channel id="replyListChannel"/>                

<jms:outbound-gateway id="outListGW"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    request-destination="requestListQueue"
    request-channel="requestListChannel"
    reply-destination="replyListQueue"
    reply-channel="replyListChannel" 
    reply-timeout="20000"
    receive-timeout="20000">
    <poller fixed-rate="5000" />
</jms:outbound-gateway>     


<header-value-router input-channel="replyListChannel" header-name="List"
        default-output-channel="nullChannel">        
    <mapping value="Driver" channel="listDriverChannel" />
    <mapping value="Stock" channel="listStockChannel" />
</header-value-router>
```

Then in some place in code I manually do the request and listen to the reply-channel:

```
    public static DriverList requestDriverList() {

    Message<String> ldrm = MessageBuilder.withPayload("DriverList request").
            setHeader("List", "Driver").build();            
    try {
        ApplicationContext ctx = 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:dmclnt/config/integ-context.xml");
        MessageChannel requestListChannel = 
                ctx.getBean("requestListChannel", MessageChannel.class);
        QueueChannel listDriverChannel = 
                ctx.getBean("listDriverChannel", QueueChannel.class);


        logger.info("Request for DriverList is sent to channel");

        Message dlm = listDriverChannel.receive(20000);

        String xmlDL = (String)dlm.getPayload(); 

        JAXBContext jaxbctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(DriverList.class);
        DriverList dl = (DriverList)jaxbctx.createUnmarshaller().
        unmarshal(newStringReader(xmlDL));
        logger.info("DriverList objct unmarshalled: "+dl.toString());
        return dl;            
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        logger.error("Error converting xmlDriverList to DriverList object",e);
        return null;
    } catch (RuntimeException e){
        logger.error(e); 
        return null;
    } 
}
```

But I receive

```
"MessageTimeoutException: failed to receive JMS response within timeout of: 20000ms"
```

all the time.
When I look through server log I see that reply with correct payload was successfully sent from server to client and, moreover,
the reply is placed into REPLY_LIST_QUEUE, as I can see in ActiveMQ admin console.
And nothing more happens!
Message in REPLY_LIST_QUEUE **With_Correct_Payload** resides in Pending and Enqueued state in this queue.
No messages are Dequeued.
It seems, JmsOutboundGateway does not pick up messages from reply-destination queue, despite receive-timeout="20000ms" delay is far more than enough to get the reply.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the outbound gateway has some expectations regarding message correlation. With your configuration, I think, the gateway expects the server to return the inbound message id in the correlation id. It uses a message selector to receive its replies.

If you use an inbound gateway on the server, it will handle the correlation for you.

Is there any particular reason you chose to use discrete channel adapters on the server instead of an inbound gateway?

You might want to consider moving up to 2.2.3, where some improvements were made to the outbound gateway (but it still requires proper correlation by the server).

EDIT: Per your comment below...

If you do want to use a pair of adapters instead, with your current configuration you would have to use a `<header-enricher/>` to copy the inbound header `jms_messageid` to `jms_correlationId`.

Alternatively, on the client side (outbound gateway), set the `correlation-key` attribute to `JmsCorrelationId`. This will cause the gateway to populate that header on the outbound message and you won't need anything on server side.

Comment: Thanks, Gary, for your reply

Comment: Thanks,Gary,for your reply and I'm very sorry for delay in commenting-I've been on the trip.As a matter of fact,it turned out that there's no particular reason to not using inbound-gateway.But I'd been thinking there is.:). So, everything is working OK with outbound and inbound gateways.But, what if I really have some reason to make two separate channel adapters (inbound and outbound) at server?What kind of correlation I might make at server? Use setCorrelationId,for instance?AFAIK,using service-activator (i.e. working with SI message, and I MUST use service-activators)I can't get JMS Headers?